# access a Groovy file in GSP

Tags: groovy, import, gsp

So I am trying to access a groovy function inside my GSP.  I have

```
<%@ page import = company.ConstantsFile %>
```

Then later in the gsp I have

```
I have been in the heating and cooling business for <%daysBetween()%>
```

And my ConstantsFile.groovy

```
package company


import static java.util.Calendar.*

class ConstantsFile {

    def daysBetween() {
        def startDate = Calendar.instance
        def m = [:]
        m[YEAR] = 2004
        m[MONTH] = "JUNE"
        m[DATE] = 26
        startDate.set(m)
        def today = Calendar.instance

        return today - startDate
    }
}
```

edit: error message:

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method:
```

Answer (score 0):

Import is fine, but Groovy is object oriented language. You need (like in JSP/JAVA) call method through an object, so first make an ConstantsFile class instance or define method daysBetween as static like this:

```
class ConstantsFile {
    static daysBetween() {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Now you can do at the GSP file

```
<%= ConstantsFile.daysBetween() %>
```

Notice the equal sign. Without it the value returned from method won't be 'printed' into resulting html.

Are you using Grails? If yes then much better will be call daysBetween() method at controller level and return result as part of the model into the view.

Tip: check [Groovy TimeCategory](http://groovycookbook.org/basic_types/dates_times/) (scroll to "Using Groovy's Time Category")

One last thing. Logic of daysBetween() method doesn't seem to be constant. So embedding it as part of ConstantFile class violates the contract. In a matter of fact, there is not much about "file" in this class either :)